# Multiple bootstrap tabs inside of eachother

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to do tabs inside of tabs like so:

```
     <div class="panel-body">
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="tabs">
             <li class="active" id="general_tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#general"><?php echo System::translate("General"); ?></a></li>

             <li class="" id="communication_tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#communication"><?php echo System::translate("Communication"); ?></a></li>

             <li id="employment_history_tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#employment_history"><?php echo System::translate("Employment"); ?></a></li>

             <li id="qualification_history_tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#qualification_history"><?php echo System::translate("Qualification"); ?></a></li>

             <li class="" id="certificate_tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#certificates"><?php echo System::translate("Certificates"); ?></a></li>
         </ul>

         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="general">

              <div class="tab-pane" id="qualification_history">

                  <div class="panel-body">
                      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="qualification_tabs">
                          <li class="" id="qualification_add"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#qualification_add"><?php echo System::translate("Add qualification"); ?></a></li>
                          <li class="active" id="qualification_overview"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#qualification_overview"><?php echo System::translate("Qualification overview"); ?></a></li>
                      </ul>

                      <div class="tab-content" id="qualification_tab_content">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

The first tab works, but the tabs inside the first tab content are not activating, so how can I get the seconds tabs (inside the first content/tabs) to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are missing all the tab-content divs for it to work properly. The correct syntax is like this:

(Element 2 has the Nested Tabs)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Nested Tabs</h2>
    <h3>Click on Element 2 to check the Nested Tab</h3>

    <!------------------------------------>
    <!-- HERE GOES YOUR NAVIGATION LIST -->
    <!------------------------------------>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#element1">Element 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#element2">Element 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#element3">Element 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#element4">Element 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- THE CLASS "TAB-CONTENT" IS SELF EXPLANATORY IN ITS NAME -->
    <!-- USE IT TO ADD ALL YOUR DIVS WITH THE CORRECT ID FROM THE NAV-->

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="element1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h4>Element 1</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="element2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h4>Element 2</h4>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        <!---------------->
        <!-- NESTED TAB -->
        <!---------------->
        <div class="panel-body">

          <!------------------------>
          <!-- ADD A NEW NAV LIST -->
          <!------------------------>

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nested1">Nested 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nested2">Nested 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <!-------------------------------------------------------->
          <!-- USE THE "TAB-CONTENT" CLASS AGAIN TO ADD YOUR DIVS -->
          <!-------------------------------------------------------->

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="nested1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
              <h4>Nested 1</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

            </div>
            <div id="nested2" class="tab-pane fade">
              <h4>Nested 2</h4>
              <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-------------------------->
        <!-- NESTED TABS END HERE -->
        <!-------------------------->
        </div>



        <div id="element3" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h4>Element 3</h4>
          <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="element4" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h4>Element 4</h4>
          <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The code is commented to aid you on the understanding of the syntaxis.

Remember to check what ID each tab is calling so it works correctly.

Check the coments in the code to check were you went wrong in the syntaxis. Compare with the correct form to help you undestand why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="panel-body">

      <!-------------->
      <!-- NAV LIST -->
      <!-------------->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="tabs">
        <li class="active" id="general_tab">
          <a data-toggle="tab" href="#general">
            <?php echo System::translate( "General"); ?>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="" id="communication_tab">
          <a data-toggle="tab" href="#communication">
            <?php echo System::translate( "Communication"); ?>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li id="employment_history_tab">
          <a data-toggle="tab" href="#employment_history">
            <?php echo System::translate( "Employment"); ?>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li id="qualification_history_tab">
          <a data-toggle="tab" href="#qualification_history">
            <?php echo System::translate( "Qualification"); ?>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="" id="certificate_tab">
          <a data-toggle="tab" href="#certificates">
            <?php echo System::translate( "Certificates"); ?>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!----------------->
      <!-- TAB CONTENT -->
      <!----------------->

      <div class="tab-content">

        <!------------------------------------------------>
        <!-- GENERAL DOESNT NEED TO WRAP THE OTHER TABS -->
        <!------------------------------------------------>

        <div class="tab-pane active" id="general">

          <div class="tab-pane" id="qualification_history">

            <div class="panel-body">

              <!-------------->
              <!-- NAV LIST -->
              <!-------------->

              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="qualification_tabs">
                <li class="" id="qualification_add">
                  <a data-toggle="tab" href="#qualification_add">
                    <?php echo System::translate( "Add qualification"); ?>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active" id="qualification_overview">
                  <a data-toggle="tab" href="#qualification_overview">
                    <?php echo System::translate( "Qualification overview"); ?>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <!----------------->
              <!-- TAB CONTENT -->
              <!----------------->

              <div class="tab-content" id="qualification_tab_content">
                <!------->
                <!-- YOU ARE MISSING YOUR DIVS WITH THE CORRECT ID FROM THE NAV LIST OF THE NESTED ELEMENT -->
                <!------->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-------------------------->
            <!-- NESTED TABS END HERE -->
            <!-------------------------->

          </div>

          <!-- GIVE ME MOAR TABS -->

        </div>

        <!-- GENERAL DOESNT NEED TO WRAP -->
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```